# Python pandas load Excel file assign column values (variable) to another column (string)

Tags: python, pandas

Name       Amount
Rajesh      50
Mahesh      20
Jon         60
Jack        85

This data is in my excel file
Name is constant & Amount variable (changes monthly )
I want to total amount of Rajesh + Jon = 110

I have done following program .it shows following error
name 'Rajesh' is not defined
My code as below

```
import pandas as pd
top=pd.read_excel(r'E:\Python\ipc_python.xlsx',header=0,usecols="A:B",sheet_name="add")

Amount1=(top.head(4))
Series_topsheet=top['Amount'].to_list()

Legend=top['Name'].to_list()
Legend=Amount1
Total_amount_Rajesh_Jon = Rajesh + Jon
print(Total_amount_Rajesh_Jon)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to refer to variables that do not exist.

`"Rajesh"` and `"Jon"` are undefined variables even if they are names of columns in your dataframe.

Try this:

```
Total_amount_Rajesh_Jon = top["Rajesh"] + top["Jon"]
```

It may be that you need to convert type to `float`:

```
Total_amount_Rajesh_Jon = float(top["Rajesh"]) + float(top["Jon"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the names called Rajesh and Jon variable.
First step: you take the rajesh row.
Second step: take the Jon row.

```
rajesh = top.loc[top.Name == "Rajesh"]
jon= top.loc[top.Name == "Jon"]
```

then, you sum amount attributes

```
Total_amount_Rajesh_Jon = rajesh.Amount + jon.Amount
print(Total_amount_Rajesh_Jon)
```

Have a good day.